# ruby on rails drop down of array with f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have an array like this:

```
@array = [[1, a], [2, b], [3, c] ............]
```

i want to create a drop down in my view with an

```
f.select
```

the drop down should have only the numbers i.e., `[1, 2, 3, ....]`

How can i create a drop down with only the numbers and an `f.select` in my view?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev i tried to access the numbers and i can access each of them only by writing @array[0][0] for 1, array[1][0] for 2 previously i used to have my form like this <%= f.select(:connection_name, options_for_select(@array))%> but at that time my array had only numbers and so it was able to display all the numbers in the drop down –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
@array.collect{|x| x[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use. It is very easy to implement.

select(:person, :city_id, [['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...])

or

f.select(:city_id, [['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...])

Notice that the third parameter, the options array, is the same kind of argument you pass to options_for_select. One advantage here is that you don’t have to worry about pre-selecting the correct city if the user already has one — Rails will do this for you by reading from the @person.city_id attribute.

Comment: The array is already present, so the idea is to not write out all the options by hand.